# Prevent winform application from freezing

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I'm Working on a small desktop app that search text in string and show the searched paragraph in richtextbox and also create hyperlink on it. So by using hyperlink user can easily reached to desire paragraph in textfile/docx file etc.

Question: While executing a for loop to create hyperlink on searched paragraphs and show it in richtextbox my interface is freezes I loose my control on form and form controls,I think I need to use some threading model for that, is there any idea, how can I proceed to solve the issue?

Below is my code which I was try to create hyperlink in richtextbox also I tell you here, I am using devexpress richtextedit (richtextbox).

```
for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                linkRange = richEditControl1.Document.AppendText(split[i] + "\n\n");
                hyperlink = richEditControl1.Document.CreateHyperlink(linkRange); 
            });
        }
```

Also I try below code but it wasn't solved my problem.

```
for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
        {
            Action showMethod = delegate() 
            { 
              linkRange = richEditControl1.Document.AppendText(split[i] + "\n\n"); 
              hyperlink = richEditControl1.Document.CreateHyperlink(linkRange); 
            };
        }
```

Comment: Which .NET Framework and C# version do you use?

Comment: you should use C# async/await feature

Comment: I am using .NET Framework 4.0

Answer (score 1):

Use Async/Await feature.

```
private async void YourMethod()
{
        //...
        for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
        {
           linkRange = richEditControl1.Document.AppendText(split[i] + "\n\n");
           hyperlink = richEditControl1.Document.CreateHyperlink(linkRange);
           await Task.Delay(50); // wait a moment here so win can perform other operations and will not freeze.
        }
}
```

You may want to Reduce delay or increase it.

Comment: I am using .Net Framework 4.0 and above code showing me an exception **Cannot convert the lamda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type**.

Comment: Dear kindly see the image in the link so you can easily understand. [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4BF0A5ABED5ACD5E!639&authkey=!AFt6oFAanG38z0k&v=3&ithint=photo%2cjpg)

Comment: Is Dispatcher.Invoke in .Net Framework 4 or Framework 4.5? because continuously  above code showing me error. I am working in .Net Framework  4 as I mention above.

Comment: you mean Like this 'Action showMethod = delegate()
                {
                    linkRange = richEditControl1.Document.AppendText(split[i] + "\n\n");
                    hyperlink = richEditControl1.Document.CreateHyperlink(linkRange);
                    hyperlink.NavigateUri = richEditControl1.Text;
                };
                richEditControl1.Invoke(showMethod);'

Comment: take a look at this simple solution. @AhmerAliAhsan

Comment: Dear I am again telling you that await,async keywords are in vs 2013 I am using vs 2010 and framework 4 because above keywords showing me error. kindly share me dotnetframework 4 code or less.